# Is it possible to add a websites IP to an APIs IP whitelist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS api that I created which is accessible through a URL. I wanted to make this API accessible only to my front end which is hosted on a static S3 bucket. Is there any way I could add the front ends IP (S3 buckets IP) to the API IP whitelist?

So far I have tried using the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" CORS policy and set it to my website's url but this didn't seem to work and I was still able to call the API with postman.

Comment: If the user's browser can call the API on behalf of the user, then at some level the user will be able to call the API with a different user agent .. with enough work.

Answer (score 1):

S3 buckets don't have static IP addresses. Besides, the S3 bucket doesn't make the requests to your API. S3 just serves files up to your user's web browsers. Those web browsers render the web page and run the JavaScript code in those files. The JavaScript code making API requests to your API is running in each of your user's web browsers. The IP address that the API request is coming from is the IP of each of your users' laptop or desktop PC.

So no, your idea of white-listing the S3 bucket's IP address will not work.